# Cannot find module '.../dist/main'

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, nestjs

Пытаюсь запустить сервер nestjs через npm run start и получаю ошибку:

```
    Error: Cannot find module '/.../dist/main'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:815:15)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:667:27)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (internal/modules/run_main.js:60:12)
    at internal/main/run_main_module.js:17:47 {
  code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
  requireStack: []
}
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! chat-app@0.0.1 start: `nest start`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the chat-app@0.0.1 start script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
```

Попытался даже пересобрать приложение с нуля, все равно не помогло найти ошибку. Подскажите в чем проблема. package.json:

```
{
  "name": "chat-app",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "description": "",
  "author": "",
  "private": true,
  "license": "UNLICENSED",
  "scripts": {
    "db": "docker-compose -f docker-compose.yml up",
    "app": "react-scripts start",
    "start": "nest start",
    "prebuild": "rimraf dist",
    "build": "nest build",
    "format": "prettier --write \"src/**/*.ts\" \"test/**/*.ts\"",
    "start:dev": "nest start --watch",
    "start:debug": "nest start --debug --watch",
    "start:prod": "node dist/main",
    "lint": "eslint \"{src,apps,libs,test}/**/*.ts\" --fix",
    "test": "jest",
    "test:watch": "jest --watch",
    "test:cov": "jest --coverage",
    "test:debug": "node --inspect-brk -r tsconfig-paths/register -r ts-node/register node_modules/.bin/jest --runInBand",
    "test:e2e": "jest --config ./test/jest-e2e.json"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@nestjs/common": "^7.6.15",
    "@nestjs/core": "^7.6.15",
    "@nestjs/platform-express": "^7.6.15",
    "reflect-metadata": "^0.1.13",
    "rimraf": "^3.0.2",
    "rxjs": "^6.6.6",
    "@material-ui/core": "^4.11.3",
    "@material-ui/icons": "^4.11.2",
    "@nestjs/graphql": "^7.10.3",
    "@nestjs/typeorm": "^7.1.5",
    "apollo-server-express": "^2.22.2",
    "axios": "^0.21.1",
    "babel-cli": "^6.26.0",
    "babel-loader": "8.1.0",
    "babel-preset-react-app": "^3.1.2",
    "date-fns": "^2.20.3",
    "graphql": "^15.5.0",
    "graphql-tools": "^7.0.4",
    "jest": "26.6.0",
    "pg": "^8.6.0",
    "react": "^17.0.2",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.2",
    "react-router-dom": "^5.2.0",
    "react-scripts": "4.0.3",
    "typeorm": "^0.2.32",
    "web-vitals": "^1.0.1",
    "webpack": "4.44.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@nestjs/cli": "^7.6.0",
    "@nestjs/schematics": "^7.3.0",
    "@nestjs/testing": "^7.6.15",
    "@types/express": "^4.17.11",
    "@types/jest": "^26.0.22",
    "@types/node": "^14.14.36",
    "@types/supertest": "^2.0.10",
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^4.19.0",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^4.19.0",
    "eslint": "^7.22.0",
    "eslint-config-prettier": "^8.1.0",
    "eslint-plugin-prettier": "^3.3.1",
    "jest": "^26.6.0",
    "prettier": "^2.2.1",
    "supertest": "^6.1.3",
    "ts-jest": "^26.5.4",
    "ts-loader": "^8.0.18",
    "ts-node": "^9.1.1",
    "tsconfig-paths": "^3.9.0",
    "typescript": "^4.2.3",
    "@babel/core": "^7.13.15",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.13.15",
    "@types/react-dom": "^17.0.3",
    "@types/react-router-dom": "^5.1.7",
    "babel-loader": "^8.1.0",
    "webpack": "4.44.2",
    "webpack-cli": "^4.6.0"
  },
  "jest": {
    "moduleFileExtensions": [
      "js",
      "json",
      "ts"
    ],
    "rootDir": "src",
    "testRegex": ".*\\.spec\\.ts$",
    "transform": {
      "^.+\\.(t|j)s$": "ts-jest"
    },
    "collectCoverageFrom": [
      "**/*.(t|j)s"
    ],
    "coverageDirectory": "../coverage",
    "testEnvironment": "node"
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  }
}
```

[Ссылка на репозиторий, если поможет](https://github.com/MrYogurt/chat-test-app)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Я патау, я неправильно перетащил nest в api. Нужно было его просто развернуть сразу куда нужно и запускать из корня например таким скриптом:

"start": "cd api && nest start",